# How can I specify the height of a CSS grid item and justify a grid item to one side?

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, sass

So I've been making a portfolio using cards (grid items) through a CSS grid. On mobile, the cards stack on top of each other, but I've made it so the cards will be next to each other on the desktop.

**I have two problems**:

- The skills card has much more space than it needs (it's mimicking the height of the other cards)
- The contact card is at the bottom of the experiences card when I'd prefer it to be under the skills card on the right.

How can these problems?

To fix the contact card problem, I attempted to move it manually. I wasn't sure this was the best method, though.

*By the way it's made with SASS *

```scss
// attempt to move contact car
#contact {
  position: relative;
  left: 102%;
}

// code used for grid (shown in image)
#sections {
  margin: 1em;
  display: grid;
  grid-template: auto;
  row-gap: 1em;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 700px) {
  #sections {
    grid-template-columns: 1fr 1fr;
    column-gap: 1em;
    
  }
}
```

[Screenshot of the site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Cnl0.png)

Comment: Please see [ask], then revise to show some markup along with your CSS in a snippet demo. Note that you've incorrectly denoted comments in your CSS.

Comment: @isherwood My site is made using multiple ReactJS components, so I can't replicate it here...I suppose I could make a mock-up, but I don't see a point.

Answer (score 0):

To get the contact card on the right you can make the grid row 3 and play with the span of the experience card to 2 so it will take 2 'box'. Look at this link.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-row